# Error: Cannot find module './pulp'

Tags: node.js, npm, purescript

Trying to install PureScript and pulp on Windows 7 via node.js 5.3.0:

```
npm install -g purescript
npm install -g pulp
cd some-empty-dir
pulp init
```

The installations seemed to work correctly, but `pulp` always fails with the error:

```
module.js:328
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './pulp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pulp\index.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
```

index.js just contains these two lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require("./pulp");
```

`C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm` is the last part of my PATH.

`where pulp` returns

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\pulp
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\pulp.cmd
```

I tried the same with Git Bash but with the same results.
I tried reinstalling purescript and pulp and node/npm but it did not change anything.

*On another computer I had no problems. Something seems to interfere with my installation on this specific system. Environment variables, existing or non-existing directories, ...?*

I'm not familiar with node.js and do not know where to look. Any idea what's wrong?

**Edit: contents of files in path**

C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\pulp:

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=`dirname "$0"`

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/pulp/index.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/node_modules/pulp/index.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\pulp.cmd:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\pulp\index.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\pulp\index.js" %*
)
```

Just running the command `pulp` executes the "else" branch of `pulp.cmd`.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Could you report it on the repository? https://github.com/bodil/pulp

Comment: My best guess is that the pulp "bin" file that's on your path is meant to be a symlink, so that require("./pulp") would actually pick up the pulp.js which is meant to be inside the node_modules/pulp directory

Comment: Ok, no, that's wrong, I just tested on a windows VM. But index.js *is* supposed to contain those two lines. I don't know what's going on here.

Comment: I am not going to report it as a bug for now because it is specific to this machine. No problems on another Windows 7 computer. I asked a friend and he did not have problems, too. Maybe the package can be improved in some way, but I do not know what's the actual problem. I deinstalled node.js cleanly and deleted some node_modules dirs, but maybe I missed a config file which now messes with module lookup?

Comment: Hm, weird. What are the contents of those two files you get listed for `where pulp`?

Comment: I added the file contents in an edit to the question @hdgarrood

Comment: Ok, that all looks fine, mine are the same. What version of npm are you on? Have you tried upgrading?

Comment: (You can upgrade npm with `npm install -g npm`)

Comment: npm version was 3.3.12, upgrading to 3.5.2 does not make a difference, though. I had older versions of node.js installed before, and tried upgrading because I already had that error. Thanks @hdgarrood

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what else to do. I think this is a bug in node or npm, maybe report it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out that I was missing `bower` and/or `jshint`. Everybody else probably had these packages already installed since they are so common.

I fixed the problem roughly by:

```
npm uninstall -g pulp
npm install -g bower
npm install -g jshint
npm install -g pulp
```

My best guess is that some postinstall script failed. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the problem anymore. Even after deinstalling node.js, deleting the folders in `%HOME%\AppData\Roaming` and reinstalling everything from scratch: `pulp` just works now.

Comment: It definitely shouldn't be to do with `bower` or `jshint`. Pulp doesn't have a postinstall script either, so it can't be that. Perhaps uninstalling and reinstalling did it.

Comment: Or rather, it shouldn't be to do with global installations of `bower` or `jshint`. Pulp used to depend on its own version of `bower`, but now it just invokes it via the command line (so it only has to be on your PATH). It never had anything to do with `jshint`.

Comment: And even if `bower` weren't on your PATH, pulp would print an appropriate error. You definitely wouldn't see that one.

Comment: I can only guess. If there was some postinstall error, it was either silently supressed or scrolled away (the standard Windows cmd buffer is only 300 lines or so). I'd gladly reproduce the problem, yet I have no idea how. Maybe my system was broken from the start and reinstalling everything fixed it. I'm willing to try it again if you have any idea what else I need to "reset" @hdgarrood

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. My best guess is that a bad version of the pulp tarball somehow found its way into your npm cache, and you ran npm cache clean in the meantime, which was the real fix. I don't think it's worth trying to reproduce, though. Life is short :)

Comment: @hdgarrood I agree. Costed me a few hours, but hopefully nobody else hits that particular problem. Especially frustrating that it happened while doing some "Hello World" in a new language. Anyways, problem is gone and I can code now. :) I'd give you some reputation for all your efforts, but since I do not know how, let me just say Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has the same problem and finds this later: my best guess to fix this is to run the following commands:

```
npm uninstall -g pulp
npm cache clean pulp
npm install -g pulp
```

---

Why I think this will fix it:

I just encountered someone else with this same problem. In their case, what had happened was that `pulp.js` was not included in the package tarball, somehow. `pulp.js` is a file generated by Pulp's prepublish script, so it should be in the same directory as `index.js` - that is, you should have a file `pulp.js` in the following directory:

```
$ echo `npm root -g`/pulp/
```

Removing the cached version of pulp and downloading it again (i.e. the above commands) fixed the problem.